# create sonar plugin to perform user action before analysis start

Tags: sonarqube, customization, extend

I'm using sonarqube 5.6.5 and everything works fine. but  i need to perform a custom action before an analysis start irrespective of language of project and type of analysis (maven,sonar scanner or ant). how to achieve this by creating a separate extension plugin and i don't want make changes in sonar core code.

Answer (score 0):

The order of sensors is not guaranteed. Your best bet is to handle this outside of analysis, perhaps with a custom Jenkins(? Bamboo? ...) plugin.